# Can one use a class to define a jQuery child selector?

Tags: jquery, class, selector

I saw this example used here and I am wondering if it can be modified to use a class instead of an ID. The reason for this is that I would like to use this script in conjunction with WordPress.

```
$(".anyclass ul li:last-child").addClass("no-border");
```

If it will help I can post the php generated html code from WordPress.

Comment: please can you post you're html code generated by wordpress ? and tell us what exactly you're trying to achieve .

Comment: I don't understand. It already uses a class.

Comment: Sorry, i was being unclear. The examples was my modification a preexisting example. The code work now. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  It will be less efficient than using an ID selector, but will work fine.  If you can, it would be good to optimise the selection by giving the tagname:

```
$('div.anyclass ul li:last-child').addClass('no-border');
```